# How to plot contours with selected colors and formatted labels

Tags: matlab, contour, surface

I'm trying to plot contour using my computed data with limited contour labels and and colors as given in the top panel of this image:

[image: here]

But I ended up with a slightly different plot (see the plot in the bottom of the above image).
I want to modify my plot with the following three specifications

1. Restrict contour labels in 2 or 3 decimal places
2. Remove plot labels in the area where the contours are too close to  each other.
3. Plot with two colors as in the first image

Here is my code:

```
f=load('fort.15');
ngridx=180;
ngridy=180;
x=f(:,3);
y=f(:,4);
z=f(:,5);
xlin=linspace(min(x),max(x),ngridx);
ylin=linspace(min(y),max(y),ngridy);
[X,Y]=meshgrid(xlin,ylin);
Z=griddata(x,y,z,X,Y,'linear');
[c,h] = contour(X,Y,Z,20);
set(h,'LineWidth',2,'LineColor',rgb('SteelBlue'),'ShowText','on',... 
      'LabelSpacing',800 )
axis([0 6 -5 7])
```

I'm not an expert in Matlab. Please help me get the right plot.
I'm attaching my data file [here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0Bzp8cH3lMMfGaXNRakJGdndQSUU).

Answer (score 0):

Well, I got only 2 of 3. Deine the level in which the color has to change (here `scl`) and you good to go:

```
scl = 6.5; % switch color level;
[c1,h1] = contour(X,Y,Z,scl:max(Z(:)),'Color','r');
hold on 
[c2,h2] = contour(X,Y,Z,min(Z(:)):scl,'Color','b');
clabel(c2,h2);
axis([0 6 -5 7])
```

The idea here is to builed your plot from two contour objects, using `hold on` command. the vector `scl:max(Z(:))` define the levvels to show in the first contour, and the get the red color and no lables. And a similar logic works for the secound contour.
If you want to lable some red contours, or remove lables from the blue ones, you need to replace `h2` in the `clabel` function with a vector of the levels you want to lable. If you will be mo specific in the comments I'll update my answer.

[image: contour]

Changing the formatting of the lables, is probably possible somehow, but it's really not trivial, so I left it by now.

Comment: Thank you friend. It works. But I need more blue contour lines. What should I do for that?